# Why does List<Object[]> needs explicit casting to convert into Scala collection?

Tags: java, scala, casting, scala-collections

Say I have the following Java collection:

```
public static List<Object[]> javaStuff = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

And that, from Scala, I want to refer to that collection, convert it Scala collection and return an `Iterator[]` over it.

Can anyone explain to me why the following (toy) code does not compile?

```
def convertMethod[Array[AnyRef]]() : Iterator[Array[AnyRef]] = {
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
   val r: mutable.Buffer[Array[AnyRef]] = MyTestClass.javaStuff.asScala // This does not compile!  
   r.iterator
}
```

More specifically, the error IntelliJ highlights is:
`Expression of type Buffer[Array[AnyRef]] does not conform to expected type Buffer[Array[AnyRef]]`

...which was quite uninformative. Trying to run the code, the error is a bit more helpful:

```
Error:(18, 58) type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.Array[Object]]
required: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Array[AnyRef]]
   val r: mutable.Buffer[Array[AnyRef]] = MyTestClass.javaStuff.asScala
                                 ^
```

At which point, I changed the original code into:

```
def convertMethod[Array[AnyRef]]() : Iterator[Array[AnyRef]] = {
   import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
   val r: mutable.Buffer[Array[AnyRef]] = MyTestClass.javaStuff.asScala.map(_.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]])
   r.iterator
 }
```

...and it worked!

Now my question really is: why is this necessary? Is there a way to avoid that explicit casting?

Comment: A Scala Array is not the same as a Java Array, so yes, it is necessary to make the explicit extra cast (the JavaConverters methods can't handle nested conversions implicitly).

Comment: I see. That makes sense. So, in my case, is the approach I am taking the best one? Or should maybe the `map` be done on the `iterator` rather than the `Buffer`?

Comment: Actually that's wrong. a scala array **is** the same thing as a java arrayw (modulo the fact that it's not covariant in scala, but still, it's the same class).

Comment: I knew they were the same class, but I thought that the empty translation between AnyRef and Object was the culprit here. However, now that I read your answer I understand where the problem really is. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple. In `convertMethod`, `Array` is a type parameter and thus does **not** refer to `scala.Array` at all.

You should change this:

```
def convertMethod[Array[AnyRef]]()
```

to this:

```
def convertMethod()
```

Note that contrary to what shadowlands said in a comment, `scala.Array` really is the same thing as a java array (except for the fact that scala arrays are not covariant, but it does not come into play here).

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
def convertMethod[Array[AnyRef]]() =
```

to

```
def convertMethod() =
```

The first one creates a method that takes a type parameter with name `Array`, which by itself takes a type parameter of name `AnyRef` (i.e. a higher kinded type). These newly introduced names hide the built in types `Array` and `AnyRef`.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it hides `scala.Array` but not `AnyRef`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Inside of the type param list it also hides `AnyRef`, but not in the method, that is correct